# Installed Nginx with Apache Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, nginx

I installed Nginx, but I have Apache too. How I can run Nginx? When I go to my IP I am getting `/var/www/` directory. I already try to figure out solving in internet but still can't get what I am doing wrong.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run nginx and not apache2 you have two option either uninstall apache2 or stop apache2

To uninstall Apache2

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
rm -rfv apache2*
```

or you can simply stop apache2 service

```
sudo service apache2 stop OR sudo service apache2ctl stop
```

default nginx root folder is /usr/share/nginx/html or /usr/share/nginx/www

you should also start nginx just for surety

```
sudo service nginx start

netstat -ntlp will show you which port is being used by which service
```

Comment: You should add a path, where to start `rm -rfv apache2*`

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to run Apache side by side with nginx on the same machine.

Here's one way: assuming you have both Apache and nginx installed on Ubuntu/Debian, follow these instructions.

The end result will be Apache as a "master" server and nginx as an Apache virtualhost.

### Change the port for nginx

Open the nginx default site:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo cp default default.bak
sudo nano default
```

Change the port on the listen lines under *server* from 80 to 81:

```
…
server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    listen [::]:81 default_server ipv6only=on;
…
```

Save and exit nano.

### Enable the required modules for Apache

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

### Set up the virtual host

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano nginx.conf
```

Paste this in to nano:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # (optional) Set a ServerName:
    # ServerName nginx.mydomain.com

    # Set the below line to your desired subdomain:
    ServerAlias nginx.*

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Forward requests to nginx (port 81)
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:81/

</VirtualHost>
```

Note the ServerName and ServerAlias in the file above. Change these to your desired domain if you have one.

Save and exit nano.

If you don't have a domain and/or would like to run it locally only, open /etc/hosts:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Then add these two lines to the bottom (you may change nginx.localhost to what you desire):

```
# nginx
127.0.0.1       nginx.localhost
```

Now enable nginx on Apache:

```
sudo a2ensite nginx
sudo service apache2 restart
```

### View in your browser

http://nginx.localhost (or your desired domain that you configured)

### A couple of notes

- If you run PHP-FPM you'll have to set the SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT and HTTP_HOST variables to match Apache: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#variables
- If you have any issues with starting nginx always check the error.log (in Ubuntu I had to **sudo su** to even see inside the log folder)